# downloading Cyanogenmod source tree takes months

Tags: android, git, download, cyanogenmod, repo

I am downloading the cyanogen source code for two days now.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 (VBox Windows 8) to clone the Cyanogenmod 12.0 repo.

> repo init -u https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git -b cm-12.0
>
> repo sync -c -j 4

Any tips how to speed it up?

Comment: It looks like your download speed is very slow. Does that affect other things on the VM, e.g. downloading Ubuntu updates? Do you get very slow downloads on the host machine as well?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.


No the internet connection is great. 

20mbit/s

A speedtest in the guest session confirmed that my internet connection is not the problem.

Comment: I added a sentence to my answer. I accidentally posted my comment before it was finished  ;)

Comment: What are the `-c` and `-j` arguments you're using with `repo`? They aren't included in the Cyanogenmod GitHub README that you linked to, and they don't seem to be listed in [the repo documentation](http://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html).

Comment: "repo sync -c -j 4"

    I use the same values as described here:
http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Build_for_jflte#Download_the_source_code

Comment: How many cores does your VM have? Have you tried lowering the `-j` value, as suggested in that wiki page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments above, the OP revealed that [`-j 4` causes `repo` to use four simultaneous threads](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Build_for_jflte#Download_the_source_code), but that the OP's VM only had two cores.

Running more threads than you have cores often hurts performance, and increasing the number of virtual cores, as well as switching to `-j 2`, seems to have [dramatically sped the process up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219379/downloading-cyanogenmod-source-tree-takes-months?noredirect=1#comment44806341_28219379).